# Trigger to update same table data

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger to update the same table data:

TableName:TEST_INSERTTIMETRIGGER

Column:changedate

Below is the what I had Tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TESTTRIGGER 
BEFORE
INSERT ON TEST_INSERTTIMETRIGGER 
REFERENCING NEW AS  NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
declare
reqdate date=old.changedate;
BEGIN 
:new.changedate:=reqdate+1/24; 
END;
```

Null values are inserting into tablename when I tried with insert statement.

```
insert into TEST_INSERTTIMETRIGGER (changedate) VALUES (to_date(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Let me suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: In addition to trying the @schurik answer, also note that `SYSDATE` is already a `DATE` type, so in your `INSERT` there's no need to call `TO_DATE` - `insert into TEST_INSERTTIMETRIGGER (changedate) VALUES (SYSDATE)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "old"  values are all set to NULL in the befor insert trigger. you have to use `new.changedate`  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TESTTRIGGER 
BEFORE
INSERT ON TEST_INSERTTIMETRIGGER 
REFERENCING NEW AS  NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
BEGIN 
:new.changedate:=:new.changedate + 1/24; 
END;
```

Comment: It is not considering old changedate column value, I want to add one hour to existing changedate column value..and place it,  as a new column value..

Comment: the "old" values are all set to NULL in the befor insert trigger---How to get value stored

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti there is no value stored before you insert the row. What value are you tring to change? With the befor insert trigger you can only change the values you are just inserting